# python pandas: pivot_table silently drops indices with nans

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an option not to drop the indices with `NaN` in them? I think silently dropping these rows from the pivot will at some point cause someone serious pain.

```
import pandas
import numpy

a = [['a', 'b', 12, 12, 12], ['a', numpy.nan, 12.3, 233., 12], ['b', 'a', 123.23, 123, 1], ['a', 'b', 1, 1, 1.]]

df = pandas.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['a', 'b'], values=['c', 'd', 'e'], aggfunc=sum)
print(df)
print(df_pivot)
```

Output:

```
   a    b       c    d   e
0  a    b   12.00   12  12
1  a  NaN   12.30  233  12
2  b    a  123.23  123   1
3  a    b    1.00    1   1
          c    d   e
a b                 
a b   13.00   13  13
b a  123.23  123   1
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is currently not supported, see this issue for the enhancement: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3729.

Workaround to fill the index with a dummy, pivot, and replace

```
In [28]: df = df.reset_index()

In [29]: df['b'] = df['b'].fillna('dummy')

In [30]: df['dummy'] = np.nan

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   a      b       c    d   e  dummy
0  a      b   12.00   12  12    NaN
1  a  dummy   12.30  233  12    NaN
2  b      a  123.23  123   1    NaN
3  a      b    1.00    1   1    NaN

In [32]: df.pivot_table(index=['a', 'b'], values=['c', 'd', 'e'], aggfunc=sum)
Out[32]: 
              c    d   e
a b                     
a b       13.00   13  13
  dummy   12.30  233  12
b a      123.23  123   1

In [33]: df.pivot_table(index=['a', 'b'], values=['c', 'd', 'e'], aggfunc=sum).reset_index().replace('dummy',np.nan).set_index(['a','b'])
Out[33]: 
            c    d   e
a b                   
a b     13.00   13  13
  NaN   12.30  233  12
b a    123.23  123   1
```

Comment: Maybe someone could inject a warning message when there are nan values in the index? I don't see that it needs to be "supported" really. Manually filling is fine, you just have to know that it needs to be done.

Comment: The problem is that this is a 'feature', in that when you groupby and have a NaN it is excluded; I supposed you could have an option that controls this (and by default is false); and/or raises

Comment: I agree but I can't imagine a warning would break anybody's notion of the feature. You could even have a flag in pivot_table to not print the warning. I'm just worried about safety.

Answer (score 6):

Currently the option "**dropna=False**" is supported by pivot_table:

`df.pivot_table(rows=['a', 'b'], values=['c', 'd', 'e'], aggfunc=sum, dropna=False)`

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. tested with pandas 1.3.0. this is not working with indexes. But it works for columns ie if one of the field in values (c,d,e for your case) contains all NaN values

Comment: tried with 1.4.0 and don't work with nan in indexes