# Pandas pd.pivot_table with NaN index

Tags: python, pandas

When using `pd.pivot_table(df, index=[col1], values=[val1])`, the resulting pivot table drops results from `df` where `col1` is `NaN`.

I can pre-fill the `NaN` with `df[col1].fillna('#', inplace=True)` but that's amending the data, which I do not want to do.

I can also do `df2 = df.copy()` before doing pre-fill to `df2` as above, but my data is large, thus do not want to do extra copies unnecessarily.

Is there a way I can pivot a dataframe with `NaN` values in columns designated as index, without the resulting pivot dropping the `NaN` index and its aggregated values?

Comment: Does passing `dropna=False` affect it?

Comment: A sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

At this time there is not a way to use `NaN` in the index for pivot tables. It will be silently dropped as you've experienced. I think your best option today is to use the `fillna` route to perform your pivot.

This has been asked on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860172/python-pandas-pivot-table-silently-drops-indices-with-nans) if you need a little more color.

I also had trouble finding a clear answer; I suspected it being related to `groupby` dropping `NaN` by default. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17595) on Github and got confirmation. This is a known issue and even has a [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/12607) on it (which might be stale).

Comment: when I use aggfunc=np.sum and margins=True, the values from NaN index is added to the total sum .. which is really confusing. Do you know how to use margins=True and reflect amount without the dropped index? at least the number will tally when copied to excel - which is important in my workplace.

Comment: @idazuwaika I'm not exactly following your comment. Can you update your question with a complete code example so I can see what you are trying?