# Pandas pivot_table dropna param not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parameters, pivot-table

I'm pivoting a dataframe to look at unique value counts within groups. I know some of the grouping columns have null values and I want to include them. I can do this easily with a `.groupby([...], dropna=False)` but I would like to use `.pivot_table` as it handles the unstacking, null-filling, totaling, etc all in one function.

## Sample Data (taken from [python pandas: pivot_table silently drops indices with nans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860172/python-pandas-pivot-table-silently-drops-indices-with-nans))

```
a = [['a', 'b', 12, 12, 12], ['a', np.nan, 12.3, 233., 12], ['b', 'a', 123.23, 123, 1], ['a', 'b', 1, 1, 1.]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

print(df)

   a    b       c      d     e
0  a    b   12.00   12.0  12.0
1  a  NaN   12.30  233.0  12.0
2  b    a  123.23  123.0   1.0
3  a    b    1.00    1.0   1.0
```

## Using `.groupby` to get desired results

```
using_groupby = df.groupby([
    "a",
    "b"
], dropna=False).c.nunique().unstack(fill_value=0)

print(using_groupby)



b  a  b  NaN
a           
a  0  2    1
b  1  0    0
```

## Code I expected would yield similar results using `.pivot_table`

```
using_pivot_table = df.pivot_table(
    index="a",
    columns="b",
    values="c",
    aggfunc="nunique",
    fill_value=0,
    dropna=False
)

print(using_pivot_table)



b  a  b
a      
a  0  2
b  1  0
```

## Question

Is this a bug in the `pivot_table` function? Or am I not understanding the use of the `dropna` param?

## Version Info

- Python - 3.8.5
- Pandas - 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

`dropna=False` means do not include columns whose entries are all NaN; your issue is that the pivot table is not displaying a column with NaN as the column name. If you change the NaN value to another string, then the pivot table works as expected.

```
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna('No Value')
```

Comment: The documentation says the opposite: `dropna : bool, default True
    Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN.` So by setting it to `False` I would expect the null columns to be kept rather than dropped. Essentially what I'm trying to understand is what does the parameter do? Because setting it to `False` or `True` yields the same results.