# Pivoting a DataFrame by selecting a empty column as index shows blank output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am facing a issue while creating a pivot table while selecting multiple dataframe columns as index (to groupby data).

So when I select multiple columns of dataframe as index and if any of the columns are empty, the pivot table is appearing blank.

For example, if the dataframe is

| Country | Parent | Category | Period | Distribution | Sources | Sales 19 | Sales 20 | Sales 21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | Living room | Living room | Total | Total |  | 1,062.65 | 1,115.05 | 1,160.63 |
| Australia | Living room | Living room | F1 | Total |  | 405.27 | 440.32 | 456.87 |
| Australia | Living room | Living room | F2 | Total |  | 310.07 | 319.45 | 336.7 |
| Australia | Living room | Living room | F3 | Total |  | 347.31 | 355.28 | 367.06 |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | Total | Total | xyz | 650.44 | 683.64 | 712.21 |
| Australia | Living room | Armchairs | Total | Total | abc | 412.21 | 431.41 | 448.43 |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | F1 | Total | xyz | 248.2 | 270.42 | 281.79 |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | F2 | Total | xyz | 189.78 | 195.76 | 206.08 |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | F3 | Total | xyz | 212.46 | 217.47 | 224.34 |
| Australia | Living room | Armchairs | F1 | Total | abc | 157.07 | 169.9 | 175.08 |
| Australia | Living room | Armchairs | F2 | Total | abc | 120.29 | 123.7 | 130.62 |
| Australia | Living room | Armchairs | F3 | Total | abc | 134.85 | 137.81 | 142.72 |

As you can see the **sources** column is **partially empty**. Now using this code to pivot the table (

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index =['Country', 'Parent', 'Category', 'Distribution', 'Sources'], 
          columns ='Period', values =['Sales 19', 'Sales 20', 'Sales 21'])
```

The output:

|  |  |  |  | Sales 19 |  |  |  | Sales 20 |  |  |  | Sales 21 |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | Period | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total |
| Country | Parent | Category | Distribution | Sources |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | Total | xyz | 248.20 | 189.78 | 212.46 | 650.44 | 270.42 | 195.76 | 217.47 | 683.64 | 281.79 | 206.08 | 224.34 | 712.21 |
|  |  | Armchairs | Total | abc | 157.07 | 120.29 | 134.85 | 412.21 | 169.90 | 123.70 | 137.81 | 431.41 | 175.08 | 130.62 | 142.72 | 448.43 |

As we can see that the aggregation for the **Sofas** and **Armchair** under the Category column is shown but the '**Living room**' category grouping has been dropped completely.

No if I remove the **Sources** from index in the code,

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index =['Country', 'Parent', 'Category', 'Distribution'], 
          columns ='Period', values =['Sales 19', 'Sales 20', 'Sales 21'])
```

The output is:

|  |  |  | Sales 19 |  |  |  | Sales 20 |  |  |  | Sales 21 |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Period | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total |
| Country | Parent | Category | Distribution |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | Total | 248.20 | 189.78 | 212.46 | 650.44 | 270.42 | 195.76 | 217.47 | 683.64 | 281.79 | 206.08 | 224.34 | 712.21 |
|  |  | Armchairs | Total | 157.07 | 120.29 | 134.85 | 412.21 | 169.90 | 123.70 | 137.81 | 431.41 | 175.08 | 130.62 | 142.72 | 448.43 |
|  |  | Living room | Total | 405.27 | 310.07 | 347.31 | NaN | 440.32 | 319.45 | 355.28 | NaN | 456.87 | 336.70 | 367.06 | NaN |

Now if we see that the **Living room** has been grouped and showing up in the output.

I have also tried adding **dropna=False** but its not solving the problem

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index =['Country', 'Parent', 'Category', 'Distribution'], 
              columns ='Period', values =['Sales 19', 'Sales 20', 'Sales 21'], dropna=False)
```

Results:

|  |  |  |  | Sales 19 |  |  |  | Sales 20 |  |  |  | Sales 21 |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | Period | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total | F1 | F2 | F3 | Total |
| Country | HFB | PRA | Distribution | Sources |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Australia | Living room | Sofas | Total | abc | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
|  |  |  |  | xyz | 248.20 | 189.78 | 212.46 | 650.44 | 270.42 | 195.76 | 217.47 | 683.64 | 281.79 | 206.08 | 224.34 | 712.21 |
|  |  | Armchairs | Total | abc | 157.07 | 120.29 | 134.85 | 412.21 | 169.90 | 123.70 | 137.81 | 431.41 | 175.08 | 130.62 | 142.72 | 448.43 |
|  |  |  |  | xyz | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Because need `dropna=False` for prevent remove groups

Comment: I am using Pandas version 1.2.4. I have tried using dropna=False but its not working. I think this is applicable for values column which are empty.

Comment: Is necessary upgrade pandas

Comment: I have upgraded  Pandas to 1.3.2. The problem still persist. I have added the results after adding dropna=False at the end of the question.

Comment: You can apply a workaround by replacing any nans with a dummy value, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860172/python-pandas-pivot-table-silently-drops-indices-with-nans